# Как создать связь один ко многим в PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, связывание-данных

Доброго времени суток, форумчане!

Пробую создать связь один ко многим между двумя таблицами: Книги и Жанры. В книгах хранится номер жанра, причём книги одного и того же жанра могут повторяться. В таблице Жанры по номеру жанра можно посмотреть его наименование. С помощью средств phpMyAdmin пытаюсь связать поле первичного автоинкрементируемого ключа и обычного числового поля. Вылетает всплывающее окошко с пустой страницей и связь не устанавливается. (((

Помогите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Прилагаю скриншот со своей базой, нарисовала связь, которую хочу получить:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В phpMyAdmin надо зайти в редактирование структуры таблицы `books`, создать поле с типом int(11) и перейти по ссылке "Связи". Появится форма редактирования связей, при помощи которой можно быстро выставить нужные Foreign keys для данной таблицы.

Comment: @bitrixoid, да, спасибо))) И, как я поняла, перед тем, как устанавливать связь, те поля, которые не являются первичными ключами, нужно сделать индексами. Тогда получится.